# Mostrar y Ocultar div segun el dia

Tags: javascript

tengo este código, lo que hace es mostrarme una etiqueta y ocultarla según la fecha que le ingreso

```
var StartDate = new Date('4/30/2019 1:43 PM');
    var FinalDate = new Date('4/30/2019 1:44 PM');

        var timeStart;
        var timeFinal;

        function showStart() {
            var nowDate = new Date();
            let distance = StartDate - nowDate;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timeStart);
                 $('.d').css('display', 'block');

                return;
            }
        }
        function showFinal() {
            var nowDate = new Date();
            let distance = FinalDate - nowDate;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timeFinal);
                 $('.d').css('display', 'none');

                return;
            }
        }

        timeStart = setInterval(showStart, 1000);
        timeFinal = setInterval(showFinal, 1000);
```

lo que quiero es simplificarlo mas pero no se como, intente meter lo de showfinal en showstart pero no me funciono.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Debe haber otro modo de hacerlo aun mas simple, pero por lo pronto podrias meterlo todo en la misma funcion, asignandole variables de entrada:

```
 function show(x) {
        var nowDate = new Date();
        let distance = x - nowDate;
        if (x == StartDate) {

            clearInterval(timeStart);
            $('.d').css('display', 'block');

        } else {
           clearInterval(timeFinal);
           $('.d').css('display', 'none');

        }
          return;
```